# In c++ ofstream and vector write blank file

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

When I run my code the vector below has the correct data stored in it, but for some reason it does not write correctly to the hard-coded file path, it instead leaves the txt file blank. I'm sure it is something simple I'm overlooking.

UPDATED: Here is more complete code.

```
// Declare the necessary include(s)
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Account.h"

/* main function
Purpose: To test the creation of two classes & make sure they output correctly
Parameters: None
Returns: an int (0) */
int main()
{
    // Declare local variable
    int i = 0;

    // Create a vector of Account objects.
    vector <Random> randomVector;

    // Create three person objects.
    Person bob("billy bob", "bobsway");
    Person joe("joe joe", "cityofjoe");
    Person george("george jack", "georgetown");

    // Create three Account objects, where each account object contains a Person object.
    Account bobby(bob, 1, 500);
    Account joseph(joe, 2, 1000);
    Account george(george, 3, 1200);

    // Push these Account objects into the vector.
    randomVector.push_back(bobby);
    randomVector.push_back(joseph);
    randomVector.push_back(george);

    // Create an ofstream object
    ofstream oDataAccount("accountData.txt");

    // Create a loop to write Account data to a file
    for (i = 0; i < randomVector.size(); i++)
    {
        // Flush the output file
        oDataAccount.flush();

        // Write the data from each object in the vector
        randomVector[i].writeData(oDataAccount);
    }

    // Close the file.
    oDataAccount.close();

// Keep the console window open with PAUSE
    system("PAUSE");

    // Return a 0
    return 0;

}// End main
```

Account Class

```
// Include pragma once
#pragma once
#include "Person.h"

class Account
{

private:

    Person aPerson;
    int accountNum;
    double accountBalance;

public:

    Account();

    Account(const Person, int, double);

    Person getPerson();

    int getAccountNum();

    double getAccountBalance();

    // writeData function
    void writeData(ofstream&);

};

// Include the Account header file
#include "Account.h"

Account::Account()
{
    // Initializes data members
}

Account::Account(const Person p, int accNum, double accBal)
{
    aPerson = p;
    accountNum = accNum;
    accountBalance = accBal;
}

Person Account::getPerson()
{
    return aPerson;
}

int Account::getAccountNum()
{
    return accountNum;
}

double Account::getAccountBalance()
{
    return accountBalance;
}

// Implementation for writeData function
void Account::writeData(ofstream& output)
{
    // Write class data to the file
    output << getPerson().getName() << ' ' << getPerson().getAddress() << ' ' << getAccountNum() << ' ' << getAccountBalance();
}
```

Person Class

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Person
{

private:

    string name;
    string address;

public:

    Person();

    Person(const string, const string);

    string getName();

    string getAddress();

};

#include "Person.h"

Person::Person()
{
}

Person::Person(const string n, const string a)
{
    name = n;
    address = a;
}

string Person::getName()
{
    // Return the name
    return name;
}

string Person::getAddress()
{
    // Return the address
    return address;
}
```

Comment: FYI `ofstream oDataFile("randomData.txt");` will already open the file, you don't need to explicitly `open` after that

Comment: Your vector could be empty. Post a complete compilable example.

Comment: I'd add a check that randomVector.size() isn't 0; if it is, the file will be blank.  It would help to have a complete example (I appreciate this may not be possible).

Comment: Maybe you are checking your file content during debugging - the file content might be written just after your oDataFile goes out of scope ...

Comment: @RoryYorke I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin This is more complete I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I apply these changes to your code (the "-" are removed lines, the "+" are added)

```
--- a/main.cpp
+++ b/main.cpp
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@ int main()
     int i = 0;

     // Create a vector of Account objects.
-    vector <Random> randomVector;
+    vector <Account> randomVector;

     // Create three person objects.
     Person bob("billy bob", "bobsway");
@@ -23,12 +23,12 @@ int main()
     // Create three Account objects, where each account object contains a Person object.
     Account bobby(bob, 1, 500);
     Account joseph(joe, 2, 1000);
-    Account george(george, 3, 1200);
+    Account georgy(george, 3, 1200);

     // Push these Account objects into the vector.
     randomVector.push_back(bobby);
     randomVector.push_back(joseph);
-    randomVector.push_back(george);
+    randomVector.push_back(georgy);

     // Create an ofstream object
     ofstream oDataAccount("accountData.txt");
@@ -47,7 +47,7 @@ int main()
     oDataAccount.close();

 // Keep the console window open with PAUSE
-    system("PAUSE");
+    //system("PAUSE");

     // Return a 0
     return 0;
```

I end up with an accountData.txt that looks like this:

```
billy bob bobsway 1 500
joe joe cityofjoe 2 1000
george jack georgetown 3 1200
```

So the modified code seems OK.  This is on Ubuntu 14.04, compiler g++ 4.8.4.  What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows and Visual Studio, but your answer steered me in a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

Does `randomVector` has any data? Because if not your file will be kept empty, because nothing is going to be written.

Also, is it really necessary to open that file for writing if you don't have any data? I would check first if the vector has any data for example with:

```
if(!randomVector.empty())
{ 
    // Your code here!
}
```

I don't know what `getStuff()` and `getMoreStuff()` returns, but at least you should see the defined blank in the file, but only if your vector has some elements.

Comment: I posted some more complete code. & It isn't returning empty, it has the data it's supposed to.

Comment: What is ``Random``? Is it the same as the ``Account`` class? Your code like you did it update won't compile at least not on my system. How did you define ``Random``?